# How can I properly select a radio button using SWTBot?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, swt, gui-testing, swtbot

I'd like to use [SWTBot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) to configure and invoke the encapsulate field refactoring. The problem is that the refactoring ignores a radio button selection. I've created [a minimal project](https://github.com/reprogrammer/SWTBotExamples) that demonstrates this problem and opened [an issue](https://github.com/reprogrammer/SWTBotExamples/issues/1) to describe the problem in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the workaround in [Eclipse bug 344484](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344484) . See my [commit](https://github.com/reprogrammer/SWTBotExamples/commit/9b3dd8c105ee4921f4e58679ec8ca6ad051d669e) for how I fixed the problem.